# Openlayers2 proxy.php cURL settings for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms, proxy

We have to use a proxy to send a request to GeoServer. I created a PHP file like this.

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.php?url=";
```

is Openlayers settings.

```
localhost/myapp/proxy.php
```

is my proxy adress. Proxy content is like this.

```
<?php
$headers = array(
    "Content-type: application/xml",
    "Content-type: text/xml",
);

 $ch = curl_init($_GET['url']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $output;
?>
```

I am using this proxy like:

`http://localhost/myapp/proxy.php?url=http://somedomain.com`

Which works, such that a web page is opened.

But when I try a GeoServer WMS get query, it gives a `NullPointerException` error. For example:

`http://myip/geoserver/app/wms` is returning admin page, but

`http://localhost/myapp/proxy.php?url=http://myip/geoserver/app/wms` is returning:

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Content-Type: application/xml Transfer-Encoding: chunked Date: Wed, 03 Sep 2014 14:18:11 GMT java.lang.NullPointerException null**

`http://myip/geoserver/app/wms?request=GetCapabilities` is returning an XML page, but

`http://localhost/myapp/proxy.php?url=http://myip/geoserver/app/wms?request=GetCapabilities`

is returning plain text result.

Comment: does your "app" WMS service require different privileges to the global WMS service? It looks like you are explicitly setting the request headers sent to the remote URL (incorrectly - Content-Type can only have a single value) instead of passing the incoming headers straight through. If your browser is sending an auth header it is getting stripped out by the proxy